# SQL, Joining the same table by shifted column efficiently

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would require some help with the following situation in SQL (I use MSSQL).
I have the table

| Col1 | Col2 | TIME1 | TIME2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 2021-01-18 17:41:26.767 | 2021-01-20 17:54:21.383 |
| 1 | b | 2021-01-22 17:41:26.767 | 2021-01-24 17:54:21.383 |
| 2 | c | 2021-01-25 17:41:26.767 | 2021-01-27 17:54:21.383 |
| 2 | d | 2021-01-30 17:41:26.767 | 2021-01-31 17:54:21.383 |
| 3 | e | 2021-02-05 17:54:21.383 | 2021-02-15 17:54:21.383 |
| 3 | f | 2021-02-15 17:54:21.383 | 2021-02-16 17:54:21.383 |
| 3 | f | 2021-02-17 18:13:43.610 | 2021-02-18 17:54:21.383 |

```
CREATE TABLE Test1 
(
    Col1  INT,
    Col2 CHAR(1),
    TIME1 DATETIME,
    TIME2 DATETIME
);

INSERT  INTO Test1 (Col1, Col2, Time1, Time2)
VALUES (1, 'a', GETDATE(), GETDATE() + 2), 
        (1, 'b', GETDATE() + 4, GETDATE() + 6), 
        (2, 'c', GETDATE() + 7, GETDATE() + 9), 
        (2, 'd', GETDATE() + 12, GETDATE() + 13), 
        (3, 'e', GETDATE() + 18, GETDATE() + 28),
        (3, 'f', GETDATE() + 28, GETDATE() + 29),
        (3, 'f', GETDATE() + 30, GETDATE() + 31);
```

and I would like to join to this table the same one following the rule:
"If *TIME2 of the next row* = TIME1 or *TIME2 + 1 of the next row* = TIME1 or *TIME2 + 2* = TIME1 then left join by keeping the earlier date grouped by Col1. If no rows can be joined based on the rule above, then keep TIME1".

The result should look like:

| Col1 | Col2From | Col2To | TIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | b | 2021-01-20 17:54:21.383 |
| 1 | b | NULL | 2021-01-22 17:54:21.383 |
| 2 | c | NULL | 2021-01-25 17:54:21.383 |
| 2 | d | NULL | 2021-01-30 17:54:21.383 |
| 3 | e | f | 2021-02-15 17:41:26.767 |
| 3 | f | f | 2021-02-16 17:54:21.383 |
| 3 | f | NULL | 2021-02-17 17:54:21.383 |

Of course, I could do like:

```
select ..
from Test1 as t
left join Test1 as t1 
on t1.TIME1 = DATEADD(DAY,1,t.TIME1)
and t1.Col1 = t.Col1
left join Test1 as t2
on t2.TIME1 = DATEADD(DAY,2,t.TIME1)
and t2.Col1 = t.Col1
.
.
```

but it is ugly as hell and I believe, there is a more efficient way to do that.
The best would be by allowing a flexible number of day shift using a parameter.

Could you please help me?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean? The tag? I remove it, sorry :) It was suggested me to use that tag as well. I am beginner on stackoverflow.

Comment: You tagged [tag:sql-server-2008] @LászlóMarton . Don't tag spam. If a tag isn't related to the question, or your environment, don't use it. Doing so is likely to attrach the attention of users that can't help you, or incorrect answers. It can also attract downvotes as people you attracted with the incorrect tag can't help you, and thus you have wasted their time.

Comment: Okay, got it, tag is removed! Thanks for the note! :)

Comment: @LászlóMarton please provide your whole query

Comment: I created this sample data and sample query to point out my requirements. My whole query is more complicated and does many more things, which I don't want to change. On the other hand, to solve this special problem would help me with other queries as well. 
Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on your explanation "keeping the earlier date grouped by Col1" it mean you need to keep MIN(t.time2) but it seems in your sample output you are showing the next time2
so here is what I think you need to do:

```
 SELECT
    t.col1 
    , t.Col2 Col2From
    , CASE WHEN LEAD(t.time1) OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY time1) IN (t.time2, DATEADD(DAY,1 , t.time2) , DATEADD(DAY,2 , t.time2))
            THEN LEAD(t.col2) OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY time1)
            ELSE null
    END Col2To
    , CASE WHEN LEAD(t.time1) OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY time1) IN (t.time2, DATEADD(DAY,1 , t.time2) , DATEADD(DAY,2 , t.time2))
            THEN t.time2
            ELSE t.time1
    END [Time] 
FROM
    Test1 t
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this does exactly what I need. Answer accepted! :)